# Mod rewrite rule only on higher pages?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

my URL looks like this:

www.domain.de/de/table.php?id=clubname&page=2

i use this rule:
RewriteRule ^footballgames-(.*)/page([0-9]+).html$ de/table.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L]

to get this: 
www.domain.de/footballgames-clubname/page2.html

Everything is fine.

But i don't want it for the first page:
www.domain.de/footballgames-clubname/page1.html

it should looks like this:
www.domain.de/footballgames-clubname.html

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^footballgames-([^/]+)/?$ de/table.php?id=$1&page=1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^footballgames-([^/]+)/page([2-9]+)\.html$ de/table.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That doesn't give me any detail like what didn't work OR what error you got?

Comment: Sorry, can't answer my own question for 8 hours

Comment: You don't need to submit any answer. Just leave answers of my question here in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

domain.de/footballgames-clubname.html could not be found.
I've tested this too:

RewriteRule ^footballgames-(.*)/page([0-9]*).html$ de/table.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^footballgames-(.*).html$ de/table.php?id=$1&page=1 [L]

The URL Input works fine, but the href links for the pagination are not OK.
If i use:

domain.de/footballgames-clubname/page2.html
the pagination links are correct:

domain.de/footballgames-clubname/page1.html

domain.de/footballgames-clubname/page2.html
...

But if i use:

http://www.domain.de/footballgames-clubname.html
the pagination links only shows:

domain.de/page1.html

domain.de/page2.html

and this didn't work.